# any method to update a deprecated Teamviewer version on a remote computer for which I have the admin credentials?

Tags: windows, installation, updates, remote, teamviewer

## Background:

1. I have TeamViewer installed on several Windows PCs (friends, family, former and current coworkers) that I figured I might need remote access to some day.
2. Most of these installs have older versions of TeamViewer that are now deprecated.
3. The time has come that I now need to support several of these PCs.
4. I now also learn that TeamViewer has completely disabled all functionality with these older versions of Teamviewer.
5. The remote users DO NOT have administrative access to their computers.
6. I DO have the administrative credentials to these computers.
7. I DO NOT want to give the remote users administrative access.
8. These PCs are in remote locations that I WILL NOT HAVE PHYSICAL ACCESS TO any time soon.
9. In the older days of Teamviewer, there used to be a method where you could update a remote install of Teamviewer by supplying the administrative credentials, and then letting Teamviewer essentially perform an unattended in-place upgrade.  For some inexplicable reason, Teamviewer seems to have disabled even this functionality.
10. I can get the remote user to download and run the latest Teamviewer version under their limited user account, and I can successfully connect, but then any time an administrative task is required, I cannot see the Windows UAC window asking for administrative credentials.  This is expected behavior as Teamviewer is not running as a program with administrative access.
11. Even if I could somehow see the UAC prompt, how could I upgrade the old version of Teamviewer (in Program Files) while the new version of Teamviewer is running under the limited user's profile?  The Teamviewer install program seems to detect whether a Teamviewer instance is already running, and won't let you install while Teamviewer is running.  I suppose the answer to this is to temporarily set up another remote access program under the local user account, but then I still have the UAC issue.

## Question:

Is there any method that anyone has discovered to update a deprecated Teamviewer version on a remote computer for which they have the admin credentials?  Can I start a full unattended update from the command prompt, perhaps, supplying the necessary administrative credentials ahead of time?

Comment: Have you tried to access those PCs via Windows Remote Desktop?

Comment: Enabling remote desktop would require administrator access.